# Broken PS/2, how to access BIOS?

Tags: motherboard, ps2-keyboard

I have an old computer with broken PS/2 ports (both of  them) and also broken USB ports, and I can't access the BIOS.

Things I've tried (that haven't worked):

- multiple PS/2 keyboards to make sure the first one wasn't broken
- adding a PCI PS/2 controller and plugging my keyboard to that
- multiple USB keyboards (although most USB ports on the motherboard are also toast, I also tried a PCI USB controller, with no luck)

In all cases, I get a keyboard error and can't press the keys that get me into the BIOS.

My motherboard is one very much like [this one](http://www.asrock.com/mb/nvidia/am2nf3-vsta/), although with a PCI Express slot instead of an AGP.

Is there something I could do to fix this?

Comment: I guess maybe you might need it to see a keyboard even for the computer to get past the BIOS, let alone get into the BIOS..  I can't think of anything else you can try beyond what you've tried. An electronic engineer that is also a computer fanatic might have some ideas but i've never met one or known of any that'd be into that, even on the big world of the internet.  Why are you so interested in starting it?

Comment: serial to ps/2 converter?

Comment: @barlop it actually goes through the BIOS just fine, and Windows see my PCI connected keyboard. Only BIOS doesn't. I really want to start it because it's a pretty decent machine and I think it's a huge waste to throw it away. I could give it to a charity or a kid that needs it.

Comment: @DavidPostill what do you mean?

Comment: @FrontierPsycho With a converter you can plug a mouse (and maybe a keyboard) into your serial port

Comment: @DavidPostill that sounds like a great idea, if only I can find one of those! I'll try, thanks.

Comment: @FrontierPsycho You can get them on Amazon https://www.amazon.com/Belkin-F4A611-Serial-Adapter-MiniDin6/dp/B00000J1TW

Comment: i'm curious if you were to unplug the PCI connected keyboard, does it still go into windows?  i.e. not give a keyboard not found press key to continue error?

Comment: @barlop If I remember correctly, I always get a "keyboard not found press F1 to continue" or similar error, but it still went ahead.